# How to create a subfolder?

Tags: batch-file

How can I create a new sub folder under the name hello-X where X is a random number?

```
set /p subfolder=hello-%random%
mkdir %subfolder%
```

This is what i've done. other than the first line it doesn't work. Also, how can I create a file inside this subfolder?(if i'm successful in creating it).

Comment: Which OS ? under WinXP `SET SUB=HELLO-%RANDOM% MKDIR %SUB%` is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `SET /P` which is prompting you for input, and you are probably just pushing enter.

This is (essentially) what you are doing:

```
set /p subfolder=enter a subfolder here!
mkdir %subfolder%
```

If you don't enter anything you are just running `mkdir` which will result in "the syntax of the command is incorrect". If you do type something, it will create a directory with that name (if it is valid).

You want to do this:

```
set subfolder=hello-%random%
mkdir %subfolder%
```

To add the file, you can do this:

```
set subfolder=hello-%random%
mkdir %subfolder%

fsutil file createnew %subfolder%\test.txt 5000
```

You basically pass the same variable from before, and choose a file size (in bytes) for how big you want it to be. 5000 = 5KB

Comment: woops! haha. thank you so much! but I have a question. as I said above in this created subfolder I want to add a create a random file. for one, I know I can use fsutil file [createnew] <FileName> <Length> my question is how to direct it to my created subfolder? sorry if this sounds simple and i'm asking about it. i'm really just a beginner..

Comment: @Mazinkaiser I edited my answer. I see you chose the other one. Ohhh well.

Comment: Haha, there you go ;) just a quick question, what other extentions can you suggest for me to choose other than .txt?

Comment: Windows uses back-slashes, not forward-slashes, even if it does work. :)

Comment: How about `.sex` ? :D

Comment: @Mazinkaiser Any file extension should work - It won't actually create the file as you'd expect. It is not like .pdf would create a random pdf, it would just create the same with with a different extension. If you need to create blank files for different types (that actually work), then that is a whole 'nother question.

Comment: @foxidrive I suppose it is better to stick to the convention. interesting superuser post on that topic: http://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes

Answer (score 1):

Yep, exactly what Gray just stated.

From the bat help page:

> The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input entered by the user.  Displays the specified promptString before reading the line of input.  The promptString can be empty.

To create files within the subdir, you have two main options:

1) Create an empty file:

```
TYPE NUL > "%subfolder%\empty.txt"
```

2) Create file with data:

```
ECHO Computer name: %COMPUTERNAME% >  "%subfolder%\basic-info.txt"
ECHO User name:     %USERNAME%     >> "%subfolder%\basic-info.txt"
```

If ECHO-ing multiple lines, be sure to use the append ">>" operator for each line after the first.